# d3 globe as leaflet layer?

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

I am working on a mobile-friendly geolocation web app for backpackers.  I already use D3 for data vis and Leaflet to navigate Google Maps (and other map layers). My app has features for offline use, such as saving coords to localstorage then uploading them when an internet connection is found.

I'm currently considering using d3 to plot GPS coordinates onto an svg map projection, effectively allowing me to have an offline world map which can display the users approximate location.  Here are 2 demo's I've found which use GPS coords:

http://www.kgryte.com/gists/d3/maps/places/

http://dwtkns.com/pointplotter/

**My question is: Would it be possible to integrate something like the d3 globe in the first link with Leaflet as a Layer?**

My reason for this is I would use the SVG map as a backup for offline use, but I'd like to get Leaflet to handle markers, marker popups, zooming etc.  I would get both solutions working off the same dataset for marker locations and content, so it's 'just' a case of swapping out the map.

Are there any demos/plugins for something like this?  Is Leaflet only for tile-based maps?

Comment: Looking at the leaflet website, it would appear that something like this isn't possible, at least not without some amount of hacking.

Comment: I found this tiled solution for offline maps: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44813 but I think I'll try my luck with one svg map and non-Leaflet integration.

Comment: Anyone looking for an offline GPS map solution should take a look at my follow up question: stackoverflow.com/questions/20794519